# Using both RS232 and USB for one device

Tags: power-supply

I have two options for power sources for my board, which simply has an ATMega on it --- one is a 24 VDC source going into a switching regulator that supplies the board with 5 V. Another source is via a USB Bus using an [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm) that could also supply the board with 5 V. Is there a way I can ensure that only one or the other powers the board and not both?

Or could both these be plugged in parallel and have no effect on the circuit? (I find that hard to imagine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Arduino board does this. See the power section of their schematic: http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf

Comment: You're welcome, but generally give me an upvote and wait to accept as the right answer until a little bit longer. Someone else who might've come along with a more insightful or more efficient answer could avoid answering since they now see the question as solved.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't upvote because I don't have enough of a rep :-/

Comment: Oh, well you should at least wait to mark it as correct.